# How to queue in vb.net using phpmyadmin database records ORDERING PROCESS

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm using VB.net as platform and localhost as the database. How can I queue the orders from database?

The process is the customer will order in an android app then the order details will be saved in localhost server then ill use vb.net platform to perform the queue of orders.

Answer (score -1):

I will use timestamp record from the database and use it as a reference for queueing the orders for vb.net application.